# sql order by not working in classic asp loop

Tags: html, sql, asp-classic, vbscript, while-loop

I have a sql query that orders the rows by an id, however it doesn't seem to output the data in order when in classic asp:

```
sSQL = "SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY ID DESC"
Set RS = ConnStr.Execute(sSQL)

<% DO WHILE NOT RS.EOF %> <td>
<br><p class='h1'>
<%=RS("ID")%>-
<%=RS("Title")%></p>
<% RS.MoveNext

Loop %>
```

Database:

```
ID  Title
1    car
2    tree
3    dog
```

wrong asp output:

```
ID 
2
3
1
```

Comment: How do you know? You are not outputting the ID...

Comment: im checking it against the database. Are you saying it should be correct?

Comment: He is saying you are only listing the `Title`, not the `ID`. It is not clear how you know that the recordset is not sorted by `ID`.

Comment: updated it to show the output. I also tested it in my script, and the output of the ID is not correct.

Comment: When you run that exact query in a SQL prompt, what comes back? Also, what is ID's data type? int?

Comment: You *really* have a table called "a" which has Id,Title just like that? If not, I suggest you create one and reproduce it. If you can't, post the ACTUAL SQL and the ACTUAL output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My fellow StackOverflowers, allow me to theorize on OPs context. It's a shot in the dark, with a little bit of experience in it. Consider this data structure:

```
declare  @mytable table (ID varchar(5))

insert into @mytable (ID) values
(' 1'), ('2'), (' 3')

select * from @mytable
order by ID desc
```

Notice the spaces before 1 and 3. Result:

```
ID
2
 3
 1
```

Since the browser will not visually render the empty spaces, OP might not be seeing them, but they might be there in the HTML.

That's the only way I can think of where `ORDER BY <field> DESC` would "apparently fail".

Answer (score 1):

figured it out. But not sure why it works. I had an open

```
< td >
```

tag that I never closed in the loop. Why would this cause the order to be off?

Comment: If you have another question, feel free to ask it. Since you solved your problem, you should mark this answer as correct.